# Create radio button for each sharepoint list item

Tags: javascript, html

how can i assign radio button for each SharePoint list item using JavaScript and add onclick function to it?

Comment: Share your code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
<form>
<label for="radio1">Radio number 1</label><input name="radio1" type="radio" onclick="myFunction()"></input></form>
```

This is the better I can help without any code :/ If you can edit your question and share a bit of code.

Hope I helped!